NX Cannot find configuration for task web:serve in Docker container
I want to Dockerize my next js app for this I have created a docker file:
FROM node:18.18.2-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/apps

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "run", "web:serve:qa"]

to build an image i use $ docker build -f Dockerfile.web -t web . command.
The Image is built successfully.
when I try to run a container from that image i get an error
> npx nx run web:serve:qa
 NX   Cannot find configuration for task web:serve
Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.

i tried using setup-docker from NX but it also gives me a lot of errors

Does the npm run command work in your non-Docker development environment?  How are you running the container?  (Are you overwriting the image's contents with bind mounts?)

yes, npm run works in the dev environment. I just build image and run it from docker desktop app

And do you have a .dockerignore file that excludes the host's node_modules tree from the image?

yes, I do. As far as I can tell Nx can't see the command I use to run the qa build
